# Have undefined in NodeJS SQL Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server

I have undefined when input data how I can fix it?

This is my code:

```
const {sql,poolPromise} = require('../config/winauth paperless')
exports.Checkskip = async function(req, res) {
try {
    const pool = await poolPromise;
    const result = await pool.request()
        .input('a', sql.VarChar, req.body.TagAlternateKey)
        .input('b', sql.Int, req.body.ProcessOfProductionKey)
       
        .query("execute [wos].[StoredInternalProcessTransactionCheckProcessBeforeReceiving ]@a , @b " ,function(err, result)
        {   
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
            else {
                res.json(result.recordset);
                console.log(result.recordset) 
            }
        })
}catch (err){
    res.status(500)
    res.send(err.message)
}
}
```

[in req.body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Qdq1.png)

[input data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFNeU.png)

[Undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ca41a.png)

Comment: Have you checked the `req.body.TagAlternateKey ` value? It seems you ain't using body parser. Check the value of `req.body` and add it to the question.

Comment: Does your stored procedure's name actually end with a space character? `[wos].[StoredInternalProcessTransactionCheckProcessBeforeReceiving ]`

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara i have a update my question

Comment: @AlwaysLearning i delete space but not work too

Comment: assuming the undefined is from the console.log(res.recordset) call, i see 2 scopes of "result", once that is a const being assigned the return value of the pool.request call, and the other being in the callback.  I would think about separating those two variable names, and then honing in on your intended access.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it i add OUTPUT under .input and in sql i add return_value like this

```
exports.Checkskip = async function(req, res) {

try {
    const pool = await poolPromise;
    const result = await pool.request()
        .input('a',  req.body.TagAlternateKey)
        .input('b',  req.body.ProcessOfProductionKey)
        .output('return_value', sql.Int)         
        .query("execute @return_value = [wos].[StoredInternalProcessTransactionCheckProcessBeforeReceiving]  @a , @b ; SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value" ,function(err, result)
        {   
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
            else {
                res.json(result.recordset);
                console.log(result.recordset) 
            }
        })
}catch (err){
    res.status(500)
    res.send(err.message)
}
}`
```

Thank everybody for help me